# AngularJS Module 'app.module' is not available

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a FrontApp that loads dependancies and I'm stuck with this error :

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module moduleApp due to:
 Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.module due to:
 Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.module' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I probably miss something on my syntax call but can't figure out :/

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="moduleApp">
.....

<script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="app/module/module.route.js"></script>
<script src="app/module/module.controller.js"></script>
```

app/app.module.js

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

var moduleApp = angular.module('moduleApp', [
    'app.module'
]);

 })(angular);
```

app/module/module.route.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.module')
    .run(appRun);
    .....
```

app/module/module.controller.js

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular
     .module('app.module')
     .controller('ModuleController', ModuleController);

ModuleController.$inject = [...];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never create `app.module` module.
On app/module/module.route.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app.module', [])
    .run(appRun);
    .....
```

And this file should be loaded before the file that contains:

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

    var moduleApp = angular.module('moduleApp', [
        'app.module'
    ]);

})(angular);
```

Or just add on your app/app.module.js file:

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';
    angular.module('app.module', []); 
    var moduleApp = angular.module('moduleApp', [
        'app.module'
    ]);

     })(angular);
```

I recommend that you choose meaningful names for your modules, i9t is strange that you have `app.module` and `appModule` modules.

Comment: Thks Raul. I forgot this damn [] after the module name !

Comment: you're welcome. This kind of things hapend very often