# PhantomJS cannot open a page. Angular 1.6.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs

I use phantomjs 2.1.1 and mocha for functional testing, frontend writing is on angular 1.6.5.

When I do a `page.open()`, I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the 
module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you 
specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/nomod?p0=app
https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:2299:71
ensure@https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:2218:45
module@https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:2295:20
https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:4933:35
forEach@https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:410:24
loadModules@https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:4917:12
createInjector@https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:4839:30
doBootstrap@https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:1949:34
bootstrap@https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:1970:23
angularInit@https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:1855:14
https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:33826:16
trigger@https://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js:3468:7
```

In the Chrome browser, the page opens correctly.

Comment: Did you try a web search for that error message. Seems like a common issue. Also, you will need to supply more than just the error output. Where is the relevant JS for the app module? Probable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30640214/1531971

Comment: Thanks, I try search, but this error occurs only in phantomjs browser.

Comment: Details like this should be in the _body_ of the question.

Comment: Reviewed syntax and structure

Comment: I encountered the same error while trying to run my tests on phantomJS. The problem appeared to be in angular controllers written within ECMAScript 6 specification. In particular, '**=>**' notation was used to design JS functions. Replacement these notations with more common '**function**' keyword solved the problem.